# Is this the idiomatic way to share a closure callback among threads in rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures, mutex

I'd like to pass a callback function `do_something` to a function `new` which in turn creates several threads that need the callback (here by calling a function in `LibThreaded`). For instance such a situation occurs if I have a lib that receives socket messages in a thread and then calls the callback to do something with them. The callback may itself call code from another lib `OtherLib`, for which the `Clone`trait must be implement so far.

I came up with a version that appears to work but it looks overly complex. Is this really the correct/best way to share the callback? Would it be possible to lift the `Clone`trait requirement on the `do_something` function in some other way?

```rust
#![feature(async_await)]
#![warn(rust_2018_idioms)]
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::error::Error;
use tokio::{runtime::Runtime};

#[derive(Clone)]
struct OtherLib { }

impl OtherLib {
    pub fn do_something(&self, text1: String, text2: String) {
        println!("doing something in other lib: {} + {}", text1, text2);
    }
}

type Callback = Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn 'static + FnMut(String, String) + Send + Sync>>>;

struct LibThreaded {
    something_threaded: String,
    callback: Callback,
}

impl LibThreaded {
    pub fn new(callback: Option<impl 'static + FnMut(String, String) + Send + Sync + Clone>) -> LibThreaded {
        if callback.is_some() {
            LibThreaded { something_threaded: "I am in a thread: ".to_string(), callback: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(callback.unwrap()))) }
        } else {
            LibThreaded { something_threaded: "I am in a thread: ".to_string(), callback: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(|_,_| {}))) }
        }

    }

    async fn receiving(&mut self) {
        println!("in receiving loop");
            let c = &mut *self.callback.lock().unwrap();
            (c)(self.something_threaded.clone(), "hello world".to_string());
    }
}

struct Lib {
    something: String,
    callback: Callback,
}

impl Lib {
    pub fn new() -> Lib {
        Lib { something: "I am lib: ".to_string(), callback: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(|_, _| {}))) }
    }

    pub fn set_callback(&mut self, callback: Option<impl 'static + FnMut(String, String) + Send + Sync + Clone>) {
        println!("in lib2");
        if callback.is_some() {
            self.callback = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(callback.clone().unwrap())));
            let c = &mut *self.callback.lock().unwrap();
            (c)(self.something.clone(), "hello world".to_string());
        }
        let mut t = LibThreaded::new(callback);

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            t.receiving().await;
        });
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let ol = OtherLib {};

    let callback = move |text1: String, text2: String| {
            ol.do_something(text1, text2);
    };

    let rt = Runtime::new()?;
    rt.block_on(async {
        let mut lib = Lib::new();
        lib.set_callback(Some(callback));
    });
    rt.shutdown_on_idle();
    Ok(())
}
```

Using the program above, I get the correct output:

```
in lib2
doing something in other lib: I am lib:  + hello world
in receiving loop
doing something in other lib: I am in a thread:  + hello world
```

I am wondering if there is an easier solution without `Arc<Mutex<Box...` that does not impose additional requirements on `fn do_something`. Thanks for your help!

**Edited version:**
Thanks to the help from the comments/answers below, I have the following working code (see comments for line 1 and 2 in answer by rodrigo):

```rust
#![feature(async_await)]
#![warn(rust_2018_idioms)]
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::error::Error;
use tokio::{runtime::Runtime};

#[derive(Clone)]
struct OtherLib { }

impl OtherLib {
    pub fn do_something(&self, text1: String, text2: String) {
        println!("doing something in other lib: {} + {}", text1, text2);
    }
}

type Callback = Arc<Mutex<dyn 'static + FnMut(String, String) + Send + Sync>>;

struct LibThreaded {
    something_threaded: String,
    callback: Callback,
}

impl LibThreaded {
    pub fn new(callback: Option<Callback>) -> LibThreaded {
        LibThreaded {
            something_threaded: "I am in a thread: ".to_string(),
            callback: callback.unwrap_or_else(|| Arc::new(Mutex::new(|_,_| {})))
        }
    }

    async fn receiving(&mut self) {
        println!("in receiving loop");
            let c = &mut *self.callback.lock().unwrap();
            (c)(self.something_threaded.clone(), "hello world".to_string());
    }
}

struct Lib {
    something: String,
    callback: Callback,
}

impl Lib {
    pub fn new() -> Lib {
        Lib { something: "I am lib: ".to_string(), callback: Arc::new(Mutex::new(|_, _| {})) }
    }

    pub async fn set_callback(&mut self, callback: Option<impl 'static + FnMut(String, String) + Send + Sync>) {
        println!("in lib2");
        let callback = callback.map(|cb| Arc::new(Mutex::new(cb)) as Callback); //line 1
        if let Some(cb) = &callback {  //line 2
            self.callback = cb.clone();
            let c = &mut *self.callback.lock().unwrap();
            (c)(self.something.clone(), "hello world".to_string());
        }
        let mut t = LibThreaded::new(callback);

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            t.receiving().await;
        });
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let ol = OtherLib {};

    let callback = move |text1: String, text2: String| {
            ol.do_something(text1, text2);
    };

    let rt = Runtime::new()?;
    rt.block_on(async {
        let mut lib = Lib::new();
        lib.set_callback(Some(callback)).await;
    });
    rt.shutdown_on_idle();
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: The `Box` seems unnecessary.

Comment: The `Option::is_some() + .unwrap()` is anti-idomatic. use `Option::unwrap_or`, `Option::unwrap_or_else` or even a plain old `match`.

Comment: `Arc` is always cloneable, even if the underlying is not. If you make `LibThreaded::new` take a `Option<Callback>` you won't need the `Clone` restriction in the function itself.

Comment: @trentcl: This appears to work. I post an edited version above.

Comment: @rodrigo regarding is_some. I'd like to use your suggestion, but if I use `let c = callback.unwrap_or(|_,_| {});
    LibThreaded { something_threaded: "I am in a thread: ".to_string(), callback: Arc::new(Mutex::new(c)) }` I get the error `type parameter expected, found closure`. How can I solve this?

Comment: @rodrigo regarding clone. Yes, I can make LibThreaded take Option<Callback>, but then I still have to use clone in set_callback because it is cloned for self.callback.

Comment: @DanielSchaadt: Not if in `set_callback` you first wrap it in an `Arc`, something like `let callback = callback.map(|f| Arc::new(Mutex::new(f)))`. Then you will be cloning the `Arc`, not the `Fn`.

Comment: @DanielSchaadt: Your error from the comment above is because `unwrap_or()` requires the value to be the same type as that inside the `Option`; your `Option` contains a `Callback`, that is an `Arc<...>` but you are passing a closure. See my answer below for a complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me rewrite the interesting pieces of code, as I understand the idiomatic Rust:

First, the `LibThreaded::new` can be easily rewritten with a call to `unwrap_or_else`:

```
pub fn new(callback: Option<Callback>) -> LibThreaded {
    LibThreaded {
        something_threaded: "I am in a thread: ".to_string(),
        callback: callback.unwrap_or_else(|| Arc::new(Mutex::new(|_,_| {})))
    }
}
```

You could also use `Option::unwrap_or`, but this way is nicer because you allocate the `Mutex` lazily, that is if `Option` is `Some` it will cost you nothing.

Then the `Lib::set_callback` can be improved with a few changes: first remove the `Clone` requirement; then use `if let Some(...)` instead of `is_some()`; finally convert the callback into a `Callback` soon so it can be cloned:

```
pub async fn set_callback(&mut self, callback: Option<impl FnMut(String, String) + Send + Sync + 'static>) {
    let callback = callback.map(|cb| Arc::new(Mutex::new(cb)) as Callback); //line 1
    if let Some(cb) = &callback {  //line 2
        self.callback = cb.clone();
        let c = &mut *self.callback.lock().unwrap();
        (c)(self.something.clone(), "hello world".to_string());
    }
    let mut t = LibThreaded::new(callback);

    //...
}
```

There are a couple of lines that deserve additional comments:

Line 1: The value inside an `Option` is replaced using `Option::map`. If we do it naively, `callback.map(|cb| Arc::new(Mutex::new(cb)));` we would get an `Option<impl FnMut...>` instead of a `Option<dyn FnMut>`. Fortunately we can coerce an `Arc<impl T>` into a `Arc<dyn T>` so we do just that with help of the handy type alias.

Line 2: You can do this in several ways. You could also write `if let Some(cb) = callback.clone()` (`Option<T:Clone>` is also `Clone`) or `if let Some(ref cb) = callback`. Personally I prefer the way I wrote it. The idea is not to consume `callback` in this block, so that it can be reused later.